# is it possible to press keyboard shortcuts in excel via R?

Tags: r, shell

I have an excel file that I need to periodically update before I process it further in R. The process of the update is simple - I open the excel file on my desktop and press Ctrl + D and the data updates automatically (through an add-in from a data provider).

I am now trying to incorporate the update of the file within my R code -- i.e. find commands that can open the excel file and press "ctrl + d" with the file open and then close the file.

so far I have found the command to open the file, but have not made any other progress

`shell.exec("~/example.xlsx")`

Comment: Please don't spam tags, the [tag:rstudio] tag is reserved for issues with the IDE itself.

Comment: I use an external tool to send keystrokes - https://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: @M.Viking thanks, but unfortunately cannot download autohotkey on my work computer

Comment: I believe the only way to control Excel from _any_ programming language is through DCOM or similar Windows methods. https://www.autstat.com/ has some offerings, but it is not free.

Comment: Maybe VBA macro will solve https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to execute a "ctrl+d" in Excel with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_Excel_File <- "D:/excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File)
sheet <- xlWbk$Sheets(1)
rng <- sheet$Range("B2")
rng$select()

# see https://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html for different keys
# see http://cpap.com.br/orlando/SendKeysMore.asp for different keys
# see https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-application-sendkeys/ for different keys
# ^ means ctrl
xlApp$SendKeys("^d", FALSE)
```